# Monitoring a Raspberry with nagios

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I have to monitor differents services for raspberry like CPU Load, Ram...
My pc is connected to my raspberry via a switcher.
I have installed the same version of Nrpe in my pc and in raspberry but when I test this command I got this error:

```
 CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake.
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 192.168.1.15
```

192.168.1.15 is the address ip of raspberry
Please Can you explain to me what address i should put in file nrpe.cfg

```
allowedhosts=127.0.0.1,<Nagios server ip>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you ping the raspberry from your PC?

Comment: Yes i can ping my Raspberry

Comment: It should be the IP address of your PC running the Nagios service.